# filter() (dplyr) does not distinguish between character and number?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, tidyverse

I am using the function `filter()`(in library `dplyr`) with [this dataset](https://github.com/Nayeli-Luis/stackoverflow_collection/blob/main/datasets/env.txt). It contains a variable called "depth_m" which is  numeric, I transformed it to a character class with `sapply` (see code below) and I didn't have problems.

Now the variable is a character however, when I filtered the dataset based on the "depth_m" variable either as =="20" (as a character) or  == 20  (as a number) I obtain the same result So.. Shouldn't I get an error when filtering by number (== 20)?

Here is my code:

```r
data <- read.table("env.txt", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)

class(data$depth_m)
```

Output:

```
[1] "integer"
```

```
# Variable transformation

data$depth_m <- sapply(data$depth_m, as.character)
class(data$depth_m)
```

Output:

```
[1] "character"
```

To check the data type:

```
class(data$depth_m)
```

Output:

```
[1] "1000" "500"  "20"   "1"    "1000" "500"  "20"   "1"    "1000" "320"  "1"    "20"   "1"   
[14] "20"   "1"    "120"  "20"   "20"   "365"  "20"   "1"    "375"  "20"   "1"    "1000" "500" 
[27] "20"   "1"    "200"  "20"   "1"    "1000" "500"  "25"   "1"    "1000" "500"  "25"   "1"   
[40] "20"   "300"  "20"   "1000" "20"
```

Here I'm filtering. In this code I expected to get some subdataset because the value "20" is a character and it is correct because it exists in the original dataset.

```
y <- filter(data,  depth_m == "20") %>%
  select(env_sample, depth_m)
head(y)
```

Output:

```
   env_sample depth_m
1 Jan_B16_0020      20
2 Jan_B08_0020      20
3 Mar_M03_0020      20
4 Mar_M04_0020      20
5 Mar_M05_0020      20
6 Mar_M06_0020      20
```

Here I'm filtering again. In this code I didn't expect to get some subdataset because the value 20 is a number and it is'nt correct because it doesnt't exist in the original dataset.

```
y1 <- filter(data, depth_m == 20) %>%
  select(env_sample, depth_m)
head(y1)
```

Output:

```
    env_sample depth_m
1 Jan_B16_0020      20
2 Jan_B08_0020      20
3 Mar_M03_0020      20
4 Mar_M04_0020      20
5 Mar_M05_0020      20
6 Mar_M06_0020      20
```

Any comment will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: In R, `20 == "20"` is valid, though some may think it's "sloppy". When that is evaluated, it up-classes `20` to `"20"` for the comparison. This silent casting can be good (and flexible) but it can also cause unintended, undesired, and/or surprising results.

Comment: If you want to be perfectly clear in this, then `filter(data, is.numeric(depth_m) & depth_m == 20)` will give what you're expecting, at the expensive of verbosity and stack overhead.

Comment: @r2evans, please post as an answer ...\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, the expression `20 == "20"` is valid, though some (from other programming languages) might consider that a little "sloppy". When that is evaluated, it up-classes the `20` to `"20"` for the comparison. This silent casting can be good (useful and flexible), but it can also cause unintended, undesired, and/or surprising results. (The fact that it's silent is what I dislike about it, but convenience is convenience.)

If you want to be perfectly clear about your comparison, you can test for class as well. In your example, you show `20` which is `numeric` and not technically `integer` (which would be `20L`), but you can shape the precision of the conditional to your own tastes:

```r
filter(data, is.numeric(depth_m) & depth_m == 20)
```

This will still up-class the `20` to `"20"`, but because the first portion `is.numeric(.)` fails, the combination of the two will fail as well. Realize that the specificity of that test is absolute: if the column is indeed character, then you will always get zero rows, which may not be what you want. If instead you want to remove non-`20` rows only if they are 20 and numeric, then perhaps

```r
filter(data, !is.numeric(depth_m) | depth_m == 20)
```

This goes down the dizzying logic of *"if it is not numeric, then it obviously cannot truly be `20`, so keep it ... but if it is numeric, make sure it is definitely `20`"*. Of course, we run into the premise here that there is no way that one portion of the column can be numeric while another cannot, so ... perhaps that's over-indulging the specificity of filtering.